# How to read from a PubSub sub-directory within dataflow pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am sending messages via MQTT to Google IoT core.
My Iot registry is associated to 3 PubSub topics, each topics has several sub-directory.

My messages are fowarded to PubSub and then treated by a dataflow pipeline.
In my pipeline I read from Pub/Sub as follow:

```
    common = (
        pipeline
        | 'Get common on pub/sub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
        topic='projects/project-id/topics/topics-id',
    with_attributes=True)
)
```

but I'd like to be able to read from my pubsub topic Sub-Directory, is it possible ?
I already tried to add it like this:

```
topic='projects/project-id/topics/topics-id/sub-directory'
```

not successful

Comment: Do you mean subscriptions?

Comment: What a sub directory in PubSub? Where did you see this concept? What is it for you?

Comment: I think Allison's answer covers your use case and provides you with the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge#publishing_telemetry_events_to_additional_cloud_pubsub_topics) needed. Just to clarify: seems like you mixed MQTT and Pub/Sub topic. Pub/Sub does not have the concept of subfolders as MQTT does, so you need to match each resource as indicated. Messages are forwarded to the default Cloud Pub/Sub topic instead of the additional Cloud Pub/Sub topic if the subfolder is specified in the MQTT topic doesn't have a matching Pub/Sub topic in the device registry.

Answer (score 0):

You could publish to additional subdirectory topics and have separate subscriptions reading from those. From the [documentation on publishing telemetry events to additional Cloud Pub/Sub topics](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge#publishing_telemetry_events_to_additional_cloud_pubsub_topics):

> Devices can publish data to additional Cloud Pub/Sub topics. By default, MQTT messages published to `/devices/DEVICE_ID/events` are forwarded to the corresponding registry's default telemetry topic. You can specify a subfolder in the MQTT topic to forward data to additional Cloud Pub/Sub topics. The subfolder is the subtopic after `/devices/DEVICE_ID/events.`

The documentation linked above provides more details about how to set this up, and the cases where messages WILL and WON'T be published to subdirectory topics.